# Javascript plugin written in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, plugins, coffeescript

I made an app in `Rails` and `AngularJS`. A startup approached me to port the technology over to their site, but they have very limited technology resources, so the idea is to make it very easy to integrate.

I want it to work a bit like `Google Analytics` - they include one external javascript file and add a snippet of code with a reference id/code in it. Then the rest is handled on my side.

I haven’t done this before, especially not in AngularJS. I want to use AngularJS in a section of their site without them needing to install it.

Should I just put all the directives and services into a minified file or should I have a smarter setup?

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. I'm also looking for any recommended gems/tools that can help me with this. I’m happy to explain further if needed.

**Update**

I ended up using [Brunch](http://brunch.io/), [this article](http://alxhill.com/blog/articles/brunch-coffeescript-angular/) was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a grunt build task that will inline your html templates as strings into your js, and then concatenate and minifying your code.

Comment: Thats definitely a good idea, I'm looking into it right now, if its a fit and no else comes up with a better solution then I'll mark it correct :)